# In a web application (angular) open device camera

Tags: android, angular, camera, android-camera, progressive-web-apps

I have a web application while working a tablet. This application includes camera plugin but this plugin working too slowly I wanna change this structure like that

When I opening barcode/QR code reader screen open device original camera also I wanna set this device default camera a parameter like Id or unique something after reading operation I wanna return again my web application is that possible we got any solution for this?
[image: like that]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Android camera doesn't have a barcode scanning API/feature. You'll have to manage this in your application.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin out there for scanning QR codes in Angular

Try [ngx-scanner](https://github.com/zxing-js/ngx-scanner)

Comment: I know that but I wanna open android default camera on my application this lib. open webp camera because of  slow